# Como inserir SVG dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, html5, twitter-bootstrap, svg

Possuo diversos SVG's e necessito inserir eles dinamicamente no HTML5 e com responsividade... Como faço esta façanha? Lembrando em que terei que manipular cada id do svg da imagem.

**OBS: O SVG SERÁ ITERATIVO (EM RESUMO GERAL, SERÁ UM MAPA ITERATIVO)..**

**Estou utilizando o Bootstrap 4.1 e possuo a seguinte arquitetura:**

```
<!-- PLANTA -->
<main class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
   <!-- SVG -->
   <div id="info-box"></div>
   <svg id="....." xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500">

<object  data="img/svgfile.svg" type="image/svg+xml"> </object>

   </svg>
</main>
```

**CÓDIGO JS PARA INSERIR O SVG:**

```
    // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "src/data/shoppings/lib/shoppings.json", function(data) {
    var tst  = document.getElementById("plant-src-svg")
    var rect = document.createElementNS(tst,'object');
    rect.setAttribute('type', "image/svg+xml");
    rect.setAttribute('data', "src/data/shoppings/plants/via-parque/via_parque_P1_20160909.svg");
    tst.appendChild(rect);
    console.log(tst)

})
.always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
  })
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  });
```

**Exemplo de um SVG:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="896" height="446">
      <g>
        <path style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5"
              d="m -5218.054,4636.4899 0,-54.0253 38.0905,-38.0906 6.6437,0 0,24.7146 13.2874,0 0,-24.7146 14.6162,0 0,0.5315 0,27.8058 0.4429,0 27.9921,0 0.1107,0 0,0.4521 0,48.9862 0,0.3543 0.1108,0 0,6.4666 0.31,0 0,0.8858 -0.31,0 0,6.366 0.6643,0 0,0.3543 -35.4381,0 -0.084,0 0,-0.087 -66.4369,0"
              id="1091"
              inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
              inkscape:label="#path58031" />

        <path style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5"
              d="m -5145.4162,4544.374 0,28.3373 28.5457,0 13.531,0.01 0.8859,0 0,-0.4429 a 45.062392,45.062393 0 0 1 -6.8906,-22.2343 l 0,-2.4449 -7.4155,0 0,-3.2244 -0.3987,0 -7.2523,0 -13.7303,0 -6.8323,0 -0.4429,0"
              id="1103A"
              inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
              inkscape:label="#path58033" />

              <g>
                  <path style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5"
                        d="m -5116.8705,4572.7113 14.4169,0.01 0,0.4429 -0.4429,0 0,6.6437 -13.974,0 0,-7.0958 z"
                        id="1102"
                        inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
                        inkscape:label="#path58035" />

                    <path style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5"
                          d="m -5116.8705,4579.8071 13.9723,0 0,6.6437 0.4431,1e-4 -2e-4,0.442 -14.4168,0 0,-7.0858 z"
                          id="1101A"
                          inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
                          inkscape:label="#path58037" />

                    <path style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5"
                          d="m -5116.8705,4586.8929 14.4169,0 1e-4,0.4438 -0.443,-1e-4 1e-4,6.4669 -13.9741,0 0,-6.9106 z"
                          id="path58039"
                          inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />

                    <path style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5"
                          d="m -5116.8705,4593.8035 13.974,0 0,6.8205 0.443,1e-4 -1e-4,0.4429 -14.4169,0 0,-7.2635 z"
                          id="path58239"
                          inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />

                    <path style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5" 
                          d="m -5116.8705,4601.067 14.4169,0 0,0.4428 -0.4429,0 0,6.6437 -13.974,0 0,-7.0865 z"
                          id="path58041"
                          inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />

                    <path style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5"
                          d="m -5102.8965,4608.1535 0,6.658 0.4429,0 0,0.3544 -7.5296,0 0,6.9837 0,0.2657 -1.9931,0 0,0.089 -0.8858,0 0,-0.089 -3.2333,0 0,0.089 -0.6643,0 -0.1108,0 0,-14.3504 13.974,0"
                          id="1098"
                          inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
                          inkscape:label="#path58043" />

                    <path style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5"
                          d="m -5102.4536,4622.4153 -7.5296,0 0,-7.1009 7.5296,0 0,7.1009 z"
                          id="1097"
                          inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
                          inkscape:label="#path58045" />
              </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com "inserir eles dinamicamente " Pelo código que vc postou é um SVG só, porém com vários outros "elementos" dentro, vc quer controlar cada um deles pelo ID é isso? E o que pretende fazer com eles?

Comment: @hugocsl oi hugo, bom dia! Eu possuo diversos SVG's como este em uma pasta, eu gostaria de inserir eles no HTML5 a partir de uma ação específica do usuário.. Todos os tutoriais que eu ví, foi inserindo manualmente o svg no html5, porém não é isto o que eu quero.... Eu teria um "JSON" com os caminhos de cada SVG na pasta root, e a partir de uma determinada ação do usuário o SVG seria plotado... Eu pretendo mostrar mapas iterativos para o usuário, onde ele passa o mouse em cima e aparece determinadas informações.